# Dynamically added and removed controls slower over time?

Tags: wpf, button, dynamic

For example, when I click a button called "Run" it creates a button that has a click event and adds it to a stackpanel 500 times.

I also a button called "Remove" which removes all the buttons from the stackpanel.

Is there any reason why over time when the "Run" button is clicked it takes longer and longer to generate the 500 buttons to the stackpanel? This is after "Run" and then "Remove" is clicked.

To Add a button:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Name = "Button" + i;
RegisterName("Button" + i, button);
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(buttonMethod);
stackpanel1.Children.Add(button);
```

To Remove a Button:

```
Button button = (Button)stackpanel1.FindName("Button" + i);
UnregisterName("Button" + i);
stackpanel1.Children.Remove(button);
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, it is *very* difficult to tell.  It sounds like you are not cleaning up your controls properly though.

Comment: Did you unsuscribe those button.Click event after use ?